# LogicalExpand with AlgebraicNumber present puts variables into the right hand side

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the following two test-cases:

```
Reduce[{a^3 + 1 == 0, b^15 - b^3 + 1 == 0}, {a, b},  Backsubstitution -> True]
```

Gives an output roughly:

```
(a == -1 && 
   b == AlgebraicNumber[
     Root[1 - #1^3 + #1^15 &, 11], {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0}]) || [...]
```

Whereas casting a `LogicalExpand` on top of it (i.e., `LogicalExpand[Reduce[{a^3 + 1 == 0, b^15 - b^3 + 1 == 0}, {a, b},  Backsubstitution -> True]]`) results in

```
(a == -1 && 
   AlgebraicNumber[
     Root[1 - #1^3 + #1^15 &, 11], {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0}] == b) || [...]
```

Note how the variable `b` appears on the *right side* of the equality in the second case. This is pretty annoying, as casting somethig like `/.Equal->Set` will throw an error: indeed, the variable to be assigned a value should be on the left hand side, as in the first case.

What is going on? Why is this happennig? How can I avoid this? V.11.1.1 (Linux) and V.11.3 (Windows) seems to be both affected.

Comment: Perhaps adapt your code to use `Solve` instead of `Reduce`, or inactivate `Equal` so that `LogicalExpand` won't rewrite it like this: `Activate@LogicalExpand[% /. Equal -> Inactive[Equal]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let:

```
reduce = Reduce[{a^3 + 1 == 0, b^15 - b^3 + 1 == 0}, {a, b}, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

`Reduce/@LogicalExpand[reduce]` should put them back in order, but depending on what `LogicalExpand` leaves behind this may undo some (but likely not all) of its work. If you're sure `LogicalExpand` is just swapping which side the variables are on, then you should also be able to use `LogicalExpand[reduce] /. {a_==b_Symbol -> b==a}`. Both of these work fine on the example given.

As suggested by @MichaelE2, you can also inactivate `Equal`:

```
Activate[LogicalExpand[reduce /. Equal -> Inactive[Equal]]]
```

This is probably the safest way of doing this overall, as it leaves little room for the solved equalities to be reshuffled. However, I can't guarantee that it won't also interfere with `LogicalExpand` in some unforeseen edge case.

If you want to substitute values in, try using `Solve` instead of `Reduce`, also suggested by @MichaelE2. `Reduce` is intended to rephrase a system of equations to be simpler with respect to a handful of terms (in this case, `a` and `b`), but it isn't necessarily meant to give output that can be substituted into anything. You can use `Solve` on `Reduce`'s output, which in most cases should get you every possible pairing of variables with or without `LogicalExpand`:

```
Solve[reduce]
```

As for why this is happening, I'm not sure. It's almost certainly not a bug, but the specific reasons as to why `LogicalExpand` might rearrange equalities are likely hidden away deep within the source code.

Comment: `Reduce/@LogicalExpand[reduce]` should put them back in order -- This looks to be a great trick, thanks!